# How to read request body multiple times using NopCloser?

Tags: go

Hi I am developing an authorization middleware using the `go-chi`, in the middleware i need to read the request body to perform some checks. I soon face the problem that the `request.Body` is an `io.ReadCloser` which can only be read once. I did some research and found this solution, that replacing the `request.Body` by an `io.NopCloser`:

```
if request.Body != nil {
    body, err := io.ReadAll(request.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors. Annotatef(err, "Failed to read request body")
    }

    request.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(body))
} else {
    return nil, errors.New("empty body")
}

// read the request body first time, and perform checks
err := authzCheckRequest(request)
if err != nil {
    // write header badrequest error code and stop request processing
    w.WriteHeader(400)
    return
}

next.ServeHTTP(writer, request)
```

However, the above solution doesn't work! when request reaches the endpoint handler, the `json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&param)` still throw `EOF` error.

Can someone help me on this? Did I miss any steps? Thanks!

Comment: From [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/io#NopCloser) "NopCloser returns a ReadCloser with a no-op Close method wrapping the provided Reader r". So this just adds a `Close()` function that does nothing. I'm not sure why you believe this will enable you to read the body twice?

Comment: @Brits That document is a bit confusing, I was thinking that why `io.ReadCloser` cannot be read multiple times was because the underlying stream is closed once reads from beginning to end, and since `io.NopCloser` comes with a dummy `Close()` function so it doesn't perform any actual operations to *real* close the underlying stream, thus it can be read multiple times.

Comment: Consider that a stream might be multiple gigabytes coming over a network link. The design of `Reader` allows you to process the data (e.g. store to a file) without holding everything in memory. Providing the ability to replay the stream could be very expensive (so it's left as an option for the developer).

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the root cause. Basically `io.NopCloser` cannot be read multiple times also, there is no way to reset it. In short, `io.NopCloser` is not reusable, I haven't dig into the technical reason why, but to make the above code work, there are 2 solutions:

First solution is to read the body out completely, then create multiple `io.NopCloser`:

```
body, err := io.ReadAll(request.Body)
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Annotatef(err, "Failed to read request body")
}

request.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(body))
param, err := decodeAndCheckRequest(request)
request.Body = io.NopCloser(bytes.NewBuffer(body))
```

I prefer the 2nd solution as I think it has slightly better performance using `TeeReader`:

```
var bodyBuffer bytes.Buffer
request.Body = io.NopCloser(io.TeeReader(request.Body, &bodyBuffer))
param, err := decodeAndCheckRequest(request)
request.Body = io.NopCloser(&bodyBuffer)
```

Comment: If decodeAndCheckRequest uses request.Body with a json.Decoder, you might as well pass the bytes already read and use json.Unmarshal instead.

Answer (score -1):

use io.TeeReader insteadOf io.ReadAll

```
var b bytes.Buffer
request.Body = io.NopCloser(io.TeeReader(request.Body, &b))
```